What was the purpose of the gathering mentioned in "Mekitz Nirdamim"
I came across a Sefer Called Meikitz Nirdamim- מקיץ נרדמים. I believe it was written to put forth information about a failed gathering of Rabbis in Krakow.

what was the goal of this gathering from a Halachic perspective
was the goal ever achieved


The goal of this gathering, as stated in the introduction to Mekitz Nirdamim, was to further Jewish education.
In particular, at least from the perspective of R. Menachem Mendel Chaim Landau, the author of the letters which comprise Mekitz Nirdamim, the issue that needed to be discussed, and of which he was an advocate, was formal Torah education for girls.
From his perspective, the conference was a failure.
As described in this article in Jewish Action by Leslie Ginsparg Klein,

In 1903, at a convention of Polish rabbis held in Krakow, a delegate called for the establishment of schools for girls, stating that his colleagues had neglected girls’ education. The conference almost unanimously opposed his suggestion and stated in its resolutions that Jewish parents should definitely educate their daughters at home, but for the community to establish schools would be wrong.

Eventually, of course, this goal was achieved, but through the fairly revolutionary work of Sarah Schenirer in establishing Bais Yaakov, rather than through rabbinic efforts.
